# Reduce an array of objects into another array when each object id property is unique

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript array that looks like this

```js
var array = [{
        id: 1,
        quantity: 2
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        quantity: 1
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        quantity: 5
    }
]
```

In the above code snippet two objects has same id `id:1`.
If id of two or more objects are same in the array. I want them to be converted into single object and the `quantity` property of all the object with that particular id `id:1` gets accumulated.
So the response array should look like this.

```js
var resArray = [{
        id: 1,
        quantity: 7
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        quantity: 1
    }
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692417/merge-objects-with-same-id-in-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.reduce`, you can group the array by `id` key value and can sum the quantities of same id.

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    quantity: 5
  }
];

const reducedArr = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.id] ? acc[cur.id].quantity += cur.quantity : acc[cur.id] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(reducedArr);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. well that's perfect. though i was wondering if there is anyway possible to directly recuce the array into result array(acc being an empty array instead of empty object).