# Group request information

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

Hello community, I need help.

I am receiving this information from the request:

```
0: {StationID: 'reusech3', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Battery Warning,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T18:11:45.000Z'}
1: {StationID: 'Reuse4', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Battery Warning,Glass Cracked,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T18:05:51.000Z'}
2: {StationID: 'reusech3', Working: 'Yes', Failed: '', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T18:01:46.000Z'}
3: {StationID: 'Reuse4', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Battery Warning,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T17:55:56.000Z'}
4: {StationID: 'reusech3', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Face ID,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T17:42:36.000Z'}
5: {StationID: 'Reuse4', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Glass Cracked,LCD,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T17:03:54.000Z'}
6: {StationID: 'reusech3', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Microphone,Video Microphone,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T17:35:57.000Z'}
7: {StationID: 'reusech3', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Microphone,Video Microphone,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T17:25:07.000Z'}
8: {StationID: 'Reuse4', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Glass Cracked,LCD,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T17:21:48.000Z'}
9: {StationID: 'reusech3', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Face ID,Microphone,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T13:54:42.000Z'}
10: {StationID: 'Reuse4', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Battery Warning,Glass Cracked,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T16:55:09.000Z'}
11: {StationID: 'Reuse4', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Glass Cracked,Microphone,Video Microphone,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T16:46:26.000Z'}
12: {StationID: 'Reuse4', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Microphone,Video Microphone,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T15:39:14.000Z'}
13: {StationID: 'reusech3', Working: 'No', Failed: 'Microphone,', DeviceCreatedDate: '2022-07-27T13:38:59.000Z'}
```

I need it to look something similar to this:

```
const infoReduced = [{
  user: 'reuse4',
  BatteryWarning: 3,
  GlassCracked: 5,
  LCD: 2,
  Microphone: 2,
  VideoMicrophone: 2
}, {
  user: 'reusech3',
  BatteryWarning: 1,
  FaceID: 2,
  Microphone: 4,
  VideoMicrophone: 2
}
]
```

I would only add up the "Failed". The "user" would be unique. I got to the following, but it is not adding well, could someone tell me why?

```
  const infoReduced = info.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    if (ele.Failed !== '') {
      const failures = ele.Failed.split(',').filter(ele => ele !== '')
      const properties = {}
      failures.forEach(f => {
        return (
          properties[f] = 1
        )
      })
      const obj = acc.find(ob => ob.user === ele.StationID)
      obj
        ? Object.entries(properties).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (key === k) {
              console.log('KEY PROPERTIES', key)
              console.log('KEY OBJ', k)
              obj[k]++
            } else {
              obj[key] = 1
            }
          })
        })
        : acc.push({
          user: ele.StationID,
          ...properties
        })
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
  console.log(infoReduced)
```

Return the following:

```
0: Battery Warning: 1
Face ID: 1
Microphone: 1
Video Microphone: 2
user: "reusech3"

1: Battery Warning: 1
Glass Cracked: 1
LCD: 2
Microphone: 1
Video Microphone: 2
user: "Reuse4"
```

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

On the other hand, is there a simpler way to do it? THANK YOU!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge objects with same id in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692417/merge-objects-with-same-id-in-array)

Comment: or [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [{"StationID":"reusech3","Working":"No","Failed":"Battery Warning,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T18:11:45.000Z"},{"StationID":"Reuse4","Working":"No","Failed":"Battery Warning,Glass Cracked,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T18:05:51.000Z"},{"StationID":"reusech3","Working":"Yes","Failed":"","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T18:01:46.000Z"},{"StationID":"Reuse4","Working":"No","Failed":"Battery Warning,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T17:55:56.000Z"},{"StationID":"reusech3","Working":"No","Failed":"Face ID,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T17:42:36.000Z"},{"StationID":"Reuse4","Working":"No","Failed":"Glass Cracked,LCD,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T17:03:54.000Z"},{"StationID":"reusech3","Working":"No","Failed":"Microphone,Video Microphone,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T17:35:57.000Z"},{"StationID":"reusech3","Working":"No","Failed":"Microphone,Video Microphone,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T17:25:07.000Z"},{"StationID":"Reuse4","Working":"No","Failed":"Glass Cracked,LCD,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T17:21:48.000Z"},{"StationID":"reusech3","Working":"No","Failed":"Face ID,Microphone,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T13:54:42.000Z"},{"StationID":"Reuse4","Working":"No","Failed":"Battery Warning,Glass Cracked,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T16:55:09.000Z"},{"StationID":"Reuse4","Working":"No","Failed":"Glass Cracked,Microphone,Video Microphone,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T16:46:26.000Z"},{"StationID":"Reuse4","Working":"No","Failed":"Microphone,Video Microphone,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T15:39:14.000Z"},{"StationID":"reusech3","Working":"No","Failed":"Microphone,","DeviceCreatedDate":"2022-07-27T13:38:59.000Z"}]

console.log(Object.values(data.reduce((a,{StationID:u,Failed:f},t)=>
  (t=(a[u]??={user:u.toLowerCase()}),f.split(',').filter(i=>i)
    .forEach(i=>(i=i.replaceAll(' ',''),t[i]??=0,t[i]++)),a),{})))
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it offered an explanation of the approach shown.  Also, isyourspacebarnotworking?